# Android: Camera not responding to "OK" button when trying to save image

Tags: android, image, camera

I am new to android and I am trying to make a part of my code to save image taken by my application that uses the default android camera. I want the image to be displayed in a different activity once I quit camera . Right now, if I don't save it, the image is displayed once the camera mode is quit. But if I try to save it too, the camera wont exit at all and the "OK" button does not respond. 
I am trying to build an app that takes pictures and attaches it to email and sends it along with the GPS location data.So the "send-message" part of the switch-case is for that reason.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.Picture:
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/My Images/" + "bhe_app" + ".jpg");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

        break;

    case R.id.SendMessage:  //Sending message part 

        EditTextToString();

        EmailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        EmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "myEmail@gmail.com" });
        EmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                MessageToBeReceived);
        EmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "@"+Lattitude_data +"," +Longitude_data);

        // EmailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        EmailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        // EmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(EmailIntent,
                "Choose an Email client :"));
        break;

    }

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        //iv is an image view in an activity where I display the image taken.
    //bmp is defined as being Bitmap.
    //  final static int cameraData =0


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create directory you write image.
Add this line before you create file object.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/My Images/").
path.mkdirs();
```